# NullPointerException in HandlerThread

Tags: android, message-queue, background-thread, android-looper, android-handlerthread

This bug baffled me for hours. I am getting the **NullPointerException**. The problem is this error is not consistent. It happens when I launch the app, but only occasionally. So I am not sure what is causing it.

I apologize for the verbose question with the error log, but I could not find another way of asking.

The error log is as follows:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.myproject.android, PID: 22175
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.myproject.android.ImageDownloaderThread.queueImage(ImageDownloaderThread.java:74)
    at com.myproject.android.NewsItemPagerActivity$NewsItemFragmentStatePagerAdapter.getItem(NewsItemPagerActivity.java:325)
    at android.support.v13.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter.instantiateItem(FragmentStatePagerAdapter.java:109)
    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.addNewItem(ViewPager.java:832)
    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:982)
    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:914)
    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1436)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
    at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onMeasure(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:327)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2291)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:1912)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1109)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1291)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:996)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5600)
    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:761)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:544)
    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:747)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

And the code where this is happening is shown below:

```
package com.myproject.android;

import java.io.IOException;

import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.HandlerThread;
import android.os.Message;
import android.util.Log;

/*
 * This class is used to download images in the background thread
 */
public class ImageDownloaderThread<Token> extends HandlerThread {

    private static final String TAG = "ImageDownloader";
    private static final int MESSAGE_DOWNLOAD = 0;

    // This is the handler attached to the looper
    Handler mHandler; 






    // The is used as a reference to the main UI thread's handler
    Handler mResponseHandler;

    // This is a listener object that is used to update the main UI thread with the image that is downloaded
    Listener mListener;

    // This is the interface needed when a listener is created. It forces an implementation of the callback in the main UI thread
    public interface Listener {
        void onImageDownloaded(Bitmap image, int pos);
    }

    // Set the listener
    public void setListener(Listener listener) {
        mListener = listener;
    }





    // Constructor
    public ImageDownloaderThread(Handler responseHandler) {
        super(TAG);
        mResponseHandler = responseHandler; // Set the response handler to the one passed from the main thread
    }


    // This method executes some setup before Looper loops for each message
    @Override
    protected void onLooperPrepared() {

        // Create a message handler to handle the message queue
        mHandler = new MessageHandler(ImageDownloaderThread.this);
    }


    // This method is used to add a message to the message queue, so that it can be handled later
    // ... this method is called by the main UI thread to add the message to the queue of the current thread to be handled later
    public void queueImage(String url, int pos) {

        mHandler
            .obtainMessage(MESSAGE_DOWNLOAD, pos, 0, url)
            .sendToTarget();
    }





    // This method is used to download the image  
    private void handleRequest(String url, int pos) {

        try {

            // first check if the url is empty. if it is, then return
            if (url == null) {
                return;
            }

            // Download the image
            byte[] bitmapBytes = new NewsItemsFetcher().getUrlBytes(url);

            // Generate a bitmap
            final Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bitmapBytes, 0, bitmapBytes.length);

            // Set position as 'final'
            final int position = pos;


            // We are using mResponseHandler.post(Runnable) to send a message to the response handler
            // This message will eventually result in the main thread updating the UI with the image
            mResponseHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {                 
                    mListener.onImageDownloaded(bitmap, position);

                }
            });

        }

        catch (HttpResponseException httpe) {
            // TODO: Handle http response not OK
            Log.e(TAG, "Error in server response", httpe);
        }

        catch (IOException ioe) {
            // TODO: Handle download error
            Log.e(TAG, "Error downloading image", ioe);
        }

    }


    class MessageHandler extends Handler {

        private final ImageDownloaderThread<Token> mImageDownloader;

        MessageHandler(ImageDownloaderThread<Token> imageDownloader) {
            mImageDownloader = imageDownloader;
        }

        // This method is used to process the message that is waiting in the queue 
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {

            // First, check if the message is to download an image
            if (msg.what == MESSAGE_DOWNLOAD) {

                // Call the handleRequest() function which will eventually download the image
                String url = (String)msg.obj;
                int pos = msg.arg1;


                if (mImageDownloader != null) {
                    mImageDownloader.handleRequest(url, pos);
                }

            }
        }

    }

}
```

In case you are wondering, line 74 in the error log (more specifically, this `at com.myproject.android.ImageDownloaderThread.queueImage(ImageDownloaderThread.java:74)`, references the `.obtainMessage(MESSAGE_DOWNLOAD, pos, 0, url)` line of code in `queueImage()`

---

### EDIT

According to a suggestion in **Loop**'s answer, `mHandler` is **null** when `queueImage()` is called. So, how can I guarantee `mHandler` to be intialized by `onLooperPrepared()` before executing any `queueImage()` call?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The only reason for me would be that `queueImage()` method is called before `onLooperPrepared()` so `mHandler` is not initialize.

**Update**

`HandlerThread` is simply a `Thread` with implementation of the `run()` method where `onLooperPrepared()` is called.

```
@Override
public void run() {
    mTid = Process.myTid();
    Looper.prepare();
    synchronized (this) {
        mLooper = Looper.myLooper();
        notifyAll();
    }
    Process.setThreadPriority(mPriority);
    onLooperPrepared();//It's HERE
    Looper.loop();
    mTid = -1;
}
```

So when it's called depends on starting this thread. If you start it and immediately call public method on the reference of this thread you may encounter a race condition and `mHandler` is not initialized on time.

One solution would be a delay for start processing images or playing with synchronization techniques. However, I would use much simpler way.

Just to be clear, you want your `mHandler` to be initialized just after `HandlerThread` is created and you don't want to do it explicitly from the Main Activity where `HandlerThread` is created.

**Update 2**

Just come up with the following solution.

`queueImage()` provides simple and light data. You could check if `mHandler` is null, if it's true add parameters of `queueImage()` to that queue. When `onLoopPrepared()` is called check if there is anything is that queue and process that data.

```
private LinkedBlockingQueue<Pair<String,Integer>> mQueue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<Pair<String,Integer>>();

public void queueImage(String url, int pos) {
    if (mHandler == null) {
        mQueue.put(new Pair<String,Integer>(url, pos));
        return;
    }
    mHandler
        .obtainMessage(MESSAGE_DOWNLOAD, pos, 0, url)
        .sendToTarget();
}

@Override
protected void onLooperPrepared() {

    // Create a message handler to handle the message queue
    mHandler = new MessageHandler(ImageDownloaderThread.this);
    //TODO check the queue here, if there is data take it and process
    //you can call queueImage() once again for each queue item
    Pair<String, Integer> pair = null;
    while((pair = mQueue.poll()) != null) {
        queueImage(pair.first, pair.second);
    }
}
```

Comment: But according to android documentation, `onLooperPrepared()` is called before the Looper loops. The exact wording is `Call back method that can be explicitly overridden if needed to execute some setup before Looper loops.` (for more details, here is the link http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/HandlerThread.html#onLooperPrepared() ).  Now, why would the `queueImage()` get called before `onLooperPrepared()`?

Comment: By the way, I find it cool that your ID is Loop and we are discussing Loopers :)

Comment: Just so you know, I did some testing. And you are right, `mHandler` IS `null`. I prefer your second suggested solution, but I am not willing to skip some `queueImage()` calls. How can I make `queueImage()` wait for `onLooperPrepared()` to finish execution so it finishes its intialization?

Comment: Can you show where and when `queueImage()` is called?

Comment: I like update 2, but can you explain it a bit more please? what queue are you taking about when `mHandler` is `null`? Thanks

Comment: Also, just FYI, the solution on update 1 would not work. It now causes `android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException`.

Comment: Right, I forgot that Handler attach to the looper of the current thread. We could try calling getLooper() of the HandlerThread but in constructor it will return null. I will update my answer shortly removing update 1 and I will give you an example for update 2.

Comment: Thanks a lot. You are very helpful. I am so greatful to you. It worked. I would give you ten up votes, but the site only allows one. By the way, I used a LinkedList queue insted of a LinkedBlockingQueue because this queue is accessed through only one thread (the background looper thread). Other than that, all is great. Thanks.

Comment: Be careful, as `queueImage` and `onLooperPrepared` are called from different threads normally, so messages can be lost due to race conditions. Proper synchronization is needed in this case.

Answer (score 1):

I meet same question.
I solved by calling wait() before before queueing message and calling call notifyAll() in onLooperPrepared.
This don't need additional variables that store pending messages.

Comment: This is a great answer if you can afford to block the thread. I'm experiencing this race condition in the Android UI thread, which I can't block.

Answer (score 0):

invoke getLooper() after HandlerThread.start() is call.
getLooper() will block until onLooperPrepared() is finish.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).